# Programmatic way of checking if npm packages in package.json are used in project?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I have a project written in node, with a package.json and a number of directories/sub-directories, is there any way of checking that all modules listed in package.json are actually being used in the project?

Take the scenario of multiple people committing to the project, adding npm packages here and there, adopting new ones as the project progresses, but never removing the old ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>If your objective is to remove existing packages that are not listed in the dependency list you can use `npm prune`. See https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-prune.html.</del>

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You can try using `npm-check`. See https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-check.

Comment: No, it's more that I want to remove existing packages that are listed in the dependency list, but that are not actually used anywhere

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood your question.